# Why does my array of objects built in a function return empty from the function

Tags: arrays, c, struct

I have the following structs

```c
#define MAX_NAME_LENGTH 20
#define MAX_STUDENTS 20

typedef struct {
   uint8_t grade;
   char name[MAX_NAME_LENGTH];
} student_t;

typedef struct {
   size_t count;
   student_t students[MAX_STUDENTS];
} roster_t;
```

I've built a function  to make a subarray of students from a certain grade. However, I am confused as to why the following will not work.

```c
roster_t get_grade(roster_t * roster, int grade){
    roster_t grade_roster;
    init_roster(&grade_roster);

    int i = 0;
    for (size_t j=0; j < roster->count; j++) {
        if ( roster->students[j].grade == grade){ 
            grade_roster.students[i] = roster->students[j];
            i++;
        }
    }
    return grade_roster;
}
.
.
.
// Called later
roster_t actual = get_grade(&roster, desired_grade);
```

When I add some prints for testing, I can see that it seems to be adding the students to the new grade_roster, however when I return from the function, I get an empty array.

I have since updated the function to use a helper function that adds students instead, and that works fine and I end up with a populated array when it returns from the function, but it leaves me wondering why the first solution did not work.

Thank you for any explanation.

Comment: This is not enough code to recreate the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to set `grade_roster.count`.

```c
roster_t get_grade(roster_t * roster, int grade){
    roster_t grade_roster;
    init_roster(&grade_roster);

    size_t i = 0; /* use size_t instead of int for consistency */
    for (size_t j=0; j < roster->count; j++) {
        if ( roster->students[j].grade == grade){ 
            grade_roster.students[i] = roster->students[j];
            i++;
        }
    }
    grade_roaster.count = i; /* add this */
    return grade_roster;
}
```

Comment: doh, such a simple problem I didn't see. Thank you for the 2nd pair of eyes.